# Arduino LCD with 2 DS18B20. Changing when cycle power

Tags: arduino, sensors, lcd

I'm having a strange problem that I hope someone can help with.  My sketch works perfectly when uploaded to my UNO, but when I unplug it and plug it back in, it doesn't work correctly.  If I re-upload it, it works again until power is cycled.
Once uploaded, the LCD reads:

```
Ferm:73.4  73/75
Room:75.1  75/75
```

After cycling power:

```
Ferm:73.45 73/18
Room:74.83 75/18
```

So after cycling power, I now get 2 decimal places and the "high" temp is stuck at "18".

```
 /*
  The circuit:
 * 5V to Arduino 5V pin
 * GND to Arduino GND pin
 * CLK to Analog #5
 * DAT to Analog #4
*/

// include the library code:
#include "Wire.h"
#include "Adafruit_LiquidCrystal.h"
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

//variables for temp readings
float fermTemp;
float fermTempL=100;
float fermTempH=5;
float roomTemp;
float roomTempL=100;
float roomTempH=5;

// set OneWire bus to digital PIN 4 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 4

// Setup OneWire instance
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass oneWire reference to Dallas Temp
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

// Connect via i2c, default address #0 (A0-A2 not jumpered)
Adafruit_LiquidCrystal lcd(0);

void setup() 
{
  // set up the LCD's number of rows and columns: 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // turn on backlight
  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
}

void loop() {
 readtemp();
 LCDPrint(); 
}

void readtemp()
{
  // get data from sensors
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  fermTemp = (sensors.getTempFByIndex(0));
  roomTemp = (sensors.getTempFByIndex(1));
  // check/set High and Low temp
  if (fermTemp<fermTempL) {
    fermTempL=fermTemp;
  }
  if (fermTemp>fermTempH) {
    fermTempH=fermTemp;
  }
  if (roomTemp<roomTempL) {
    roomTempL=roomTemp;
  }
  if (roomTemp>roomTempH) {
    roomTempH=roomTemp;
  }
}
  void LCDPrint() 
  {
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);  
  lcd.print("Ferm:");
  lcd.print(fermTemp,1);
  lcd.setCursor(11,0);
  lcd.print(fermTempL,0);
  lcd.print("/");
  lcd.print(fermTempH,0);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Room:");
  lcd.print(roomTemp,1);
  lcd.setCursor(11,1);
  lcd.print(roomTempL,0);
  lcd.print("/");
  lcd.print(roomTempH,0);
 }
```

Comment: That's weird.. What about resets? If you power it up and then press the reset button? If it works, try putting a delay in the setup function, then reset the LCD and the temperature sensors. If it doesn't, try it anyway. In any case.. I usually saw the opposite behavior (working at boot and not after a reset)

Comment: Thanks frarugi87.  Pressing the reset button worked.  I will try adding a delay in the setup function, but I'm not sure what you mean by resetting the LCD and temp sensors.

Comment: there should be some initializing code to set everything up at startup. I don't know the adafruit library nor the dallas sensor, but I think that there should be. Try reading the libraries documentation and/or the datasheets

Answer (score 0):

I counted your characters, 16 per line. If you have a 16X2 display, there might be characters printed beyond the screen. I suspect it was not really 18, but something larger, say 180 or 1800. That could have been a result of failed first attempt to read temperature. This reading is stuck with you as temp High. In your code, you should define a reasonable high temperature, such as 125. Don't update temp High if it is above the reasonable temperature.

To confirm it, print temp High to serial port and inspect the value.